# DAO method can be annotated with only one of the following:Insert,Delete,Query,Update

Tags: android, android-room

Im new of Room library and want to make simple project .

Here is entity class.

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is dao class.

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao extends Dao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<User> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insert(User users);

}
```

Here is AppDatabase class.

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-test")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

And here is my mainactivity.

```
User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test");
        user.setId(2);


        AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this).userDao().insert(user);
        AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this).userDao().getAll();
```

But when I run this code above . I get error behind below .

> Error:(14, 8) error: Abstract method in DAO must be annotated with
>   interface android.arch.persistence.room.Query AND interface
>   android.arch.persistence.room.Insert

I search it but cannot find anything . Thanks for any suggestion .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DAO interface shouldn't extend Dao interface.

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<User> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insert(User users);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

For my need , i've used an abstract class like this :

```
public interface IMainDao {
String getId();
}


@Dao
public abstract class UserDao extends IMainDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
List<User> getAll();

//from IUserDao
@Override
public String getId() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? I want something similar but it does not compile with complaints about wrong annotations on the base interface.

Comment: it compile in my project otherwise i ll not post this solution.